# Eclipse compilation problems

Tags: eclipse, compilation

During developping a Java project in Eclipse I encountered the problem, that Eclipse would only compile the code if I close and restart Eclipse. As you can imagine, this is quite annoying, since I cannot see any changes until I reboot Eclipse. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thx,
simon1440

Comment: Make sure you have build automatically set - 'Project > Build Automatically'

Comment: No difference there. Any other idea?